# Remove image dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I know using jquery, If I wanna load image runtime on click event, this syntax is used,

```
    $("#open_door").attr("src", "../assets/door_open.gif");
```

but If I wanna remove the same image runtime on another button's click event, then?? I want the syntax for the same

Comment: Have you tried setting the `src` attribute to an empty string?

Comment: Ya, I have but doesnt work ;< @Anthony...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't remove the image from the dom, hide it:

```
$("#open_door").css("display","none");
```

Comment: PLease read my comment above... and suggest other alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You could simply change the visibility css property of the elemenet to hidden.  This will allow it to keep its position in the page layout, but not be seen.

```
$('#open_door').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: No, because, as it is an animated GIF, animation occurs once only when the image is loaded, after that just hiding and displaying will not replay the animation, for animation replay I need to remove and add the image dynamically, not hiding and displaying it...

Comment: @Hazel I don;t believe that is the case.  Check this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/cQhPU/  When you toggle the visibility off/on, the animation still works.

Comment: You are right Mike, but in this image, the animation keeps on moving whereas in my case, just the door is opened using animation and remains opened, then nothing happens and image becomes static, so in my case it won't work... its just one cycle of animation, not the continuous one as in urs,... hope u got the difference

Comment: @Hazel OK I understand now.  Well your best bet then might be to hide the element and then when ready to display it again, quickly remove from the DOM and add a new visible element in its place (might even be able to make a clone of the original element).

Comment: @Mike...I just have to add and remove the same element from the DOM, rather than making its visibility visible and hidden because the animation works only once and that too on load of the image...

Comment: @Hazel  I would recommend you add the information about the animated GIF to the original question, so that the question and answer are more useful to future readers, as right now the way the question reads (without information on animated GIF), the are any number of possible solutions that could work.  If you have a solution that works for you now, you can also provide an answer to your own question to make clear what the actual solution to your specific problem is.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution as such there's no method available by which you can dynamically load and unload the image, The only way I found and it's working is: Take div pre-defined into the container, whenever you want to load the image, use .append("<img src='' /") and to remove it, just use $("#div").empty()... At last...

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$("#open_door").attr("src", ""); // Set the src to "" (nothing)
```

Or:

```
$("#open_door").remove(); // remove #open_door from the DOM.
```

Found this somewhere else on SO, regarding your comment on your question:

```
$("#myimg").removeAttr("src").attr("src", "");
```

Or as a last resort you could upload a completely white image to your server, and display that instead:

```
$("#open_door").attr("src", "path/to/white/image.jpg");
```

Comment: I am not supposed to remove from the element from the dom, so remove method is of no use, Basically I am using animated GIF as an image to be loaded runtime, but so giving blank src="" attribute keeps on repeating the animation, doesn't empty the image tag... So please suggest another alternative...

Comment: That's why I supplied two methods. @Hazel

Comment: I just saw your comment on your question and edited my answer accordingly. @Hazel

Comment: It only removes the src attribute of the image, but not the image completely as I want :(

Comment: I have stacked many images over one another and all with transparent background, hence uploading white pic will certainly not work... and the method removeAttr, removes the attribute and not the image and once the attribute is removed, it will create problem in again adding the image using .attr() on button click :<

Comment: I don't get why that white picture wouldn't work, if you make it 1x1 it won't be expensive to get it from the server. @Hazel

Comment: Because I guessit permanently removes the src attribute of the image and then , when I want to upload it again, it's not getting that attribute, I already tried it

Comment: Your last comment doesn't make any sense to me... @Hazel

Comment: Its ok, I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Safari.
It wouldn't let me set the attribute to a blank value.  I wanted a button to trigger a short, gif animation to be played ONCE ... in this case, Spock giving Kirk a good SMACK!!

Here's the animation: 
http://www.lowbird.com/data/images/2012/06/tumblr-lq96pfhnuq1qlc8fao1-400.gif

My solution is a bit cumbersome for my taste, but I used the .hide() method. You just have to .show() the div again at an earlier time if you want the animation to display again.  Here you go:

```
 $('#smackKirk').on('click', function(){
    $('#animate').show(); // not necessary in chrome     
    $('#animate').attr("src", "http://www.lowbird.com/data/images/2012/06/tumblr-lq96pfhnuq1qlc8fao1-400.gif");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#animate').attr('src',"");
            $('#animate').hide(); // not necessary in chrome 
    }, 2400);
```